# How to show that the hyperbolic space $H^2$ is isometric to $\mathbb{R}^2$ equipped with the following metric?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

$H^2=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3:x>0,-x^2+y^2+z^2=-1\}$ is the hyperbolic space, $\mathbb{R}^2$ endowed with the metric $$g=(\mathrm{d}r)^2+\sinh^2r(\mathrm{d}\theta)^2$$ in polar coordinates, how to show that these two spaces are isometric？I tried the natural projection $\pi: H^2\to\mathbb{R}^2$ but not succeeded.

Well, I had some new tries, since $H^2$ is isometric to the Poincaré Disk $\left(\mathbb{D}^2, \frac{4(\mathrm{d}x^2+\mathrm{d}y^2)}{(1-x^2-y^2)^2}\right)$, we can consider the map $\pi: \mathbb{D}^2\longrightarrow(\mathbb{R}^2,g)$, via (in local coordinates of the Poincaré disk)
$$\pi(x,y)=\left(\log\frac{x^2+y^2}{1-(x^2+y^2)},\arctan\frac{y}{x}\right):=(r,\theta)$$
Here I take the $\log$ to cancellate with $\sinh$, and I had checked that its Jacobian matrix DOES always non-degenerate, but hadn't checked whether an isometric yet.

Comment: Just to be sure you're aware: The ambient metric on $\mathbf{R}^{3}$ is not Euclidean but Minkowski,$$ds^2=-dx^2+dy^2+dz^2.$$

Comment: What definition of hyperbolic space are you using?

Comment: @Deane the $H^2$ defined above, with the iduced metric $ds^2=-dx^2+dy^2+dz^2$

Comment: @AndrewD.Hwang Yes I know that

Comment: Use the hyperbolic analogue of cylindrical coordinates. First, I find it easier to work with $z^2 = 1 + x^2 + y^2$ instead of the equation you stated. You can then parameterize the hyperbola $z^2 = 1 + r^2$ by arclength (with respect to the Minkowski metric).

Comment: Actually, you can map the hyperboloid to the unit disk at height $z = 1$ by the hyperbolic version of stereographic projection. Using rays from the origin, you map the point where the ray intersects $x^2 + y^2 + 1 = z^2$ to the point where the ray intersects $z = 1$. That's an isometry of the hyperboloid model of hyperbolic space to the Poincare disk model. This and more is all explained beautifully in https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~kapovich/RFG/cannon.pdf

Comment: @Deane OK, thank you and the pdf you offered, it's really helpful